# Video memory parameter in packer using VSphere ISO- builders

Tags: virtual-machine, packer

trying to add a video memory size to 16MB when VM creation using Packer provisioners (VSphere ISO- builders).but when executing following it gives the error mentioned below. any thing I have done wrong in here.

```
   "CPUs": 2,
   "RAM": 8096,
   "video_ram": 16,
   "RAM_reserve_all": true,
   "CPU_limit": -1,
```

ERROR

```
 * unknown configuration key: "video_ram"
    
    script returned exit code 1
```

Comment: You don't say which builder..

Comment: questions is now edited with required builders. Thanks

Comment: Most likely you are using an old version of Packer that doesn't support the `video_ram` configuration. Please upgrade. Also observe that it's defined in kB.

Comment: Yes thats may be the case. I have used 1.4.2 packer version and went through the documents and saw that "video_ram": parameter is not supported with the packer version. Thank you very much for the support :)